# NO REPRODUCE CLIP .Wav mi JBUTTON

Tags: java, java-swing

Muy buenas comunidad, tengo un JFrame un pequeño programita que pinta Jpanel con una mezclador en RGB, todos sus componentes funcionan bien pero decidi añadirle sonido a un boton que al presionarlo suene, hice el sgte metodo y lo puse en su respectivo ActionPerformed y ActionListener, pero por alguna razon al ejecutarlo no suena y el catch del metodo me escribe ruta de archivo no encontrada, cabe resaltar q mis variables de tipo clip estan en el JFrame junto con el resto de componentes.

```
    private void ponerBotones() {
    mezcla.setBounds(570, 350, 105, 30);
    this.add(mezcla);
    mezcla.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         try {
            //String sonido= "/sonido/clip.wav";
        //audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sonidowav);  
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("/sonido/click.wav")));            
        clip.start();
        clip.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }  
        }
        
    });
```

ese es el evento, esta bien realizarlo asi o deberia crear alguna clase particular donde pueda añadir esa funcion?

Comment: Como dice el error, no encuentra el wav. Revisa ese new File, ya que si indicas que la ruta empieza por una barra (/) la ruta será absoluta, cuando seguramente quieras que la ruta sea relativa.

Comment: Pueden ser permisos de lectura o acceso al archivo, intenta imprimir el path en donde estás buscando y comprueba que no sea problema en la ruta. Y lo siguiente coloca un sonido localizado en otra ruta ejemplo en internet.

Comment: De hecho puse ambas rutas y ninguna da, la.absoluta q es de mi paquete sonido, y allí esta el. Archivo y la relativa a directamente puse el clip con los archivos del JFrame, pero igual sigue dándome ese error asi que descarte que sea la declaración de la ruta :(